# How to customize "Create Issue" popup in JIRA 5?

Tags: html, css, jira

How to add custom HTML or CSS to that popup? Any idea?

Comment: [Atlassian's community forum](http://answers.atlassian.com/) is probably a better place for this question

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? that is it for?  There are many ways to do that, to know which is the best give more details..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you'd be able to insert your own HTML or CSS, but you can easily reorder the possition of the fields and the general look of any [screen in JIRA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Defining+a+Screen).

This is achieved through the ["Screen Schemes"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Associating+a+Screen+with+an+Issue+Operation) and ["Issue type screen schemes"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Associating+Screen+and+Issue+Operation+Mappings+with+an+Issue+Type). The idea is that you have where to change the settings from.

The basic steps you need to use could be:

1. Read the JIRA Documentation carefully
2. Re-do N:1 until you understand the documentation clearly
3. **BackUp All the data on your instance -EVERYTHING!!** The DB + any miscellaneous settings.
4. No-one should use the instance while you're changing it in order to avoid losing any data afterwards.
5. Make the changes you desire
6. Test the new changes (open/close some issues, resolve some issues). Actually test everything (you can restore the issues's state from the backup you created later on when you're sure everything is ok.)
7. Restore Data BackUp and put instance in production state